# How to find out the Joomla components base table name

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to know in which table a joomla component stores its data and I want to achieve this programmatically. (I already know through phpmyadmin the relevant tables a component stores data in.) For eg. if I know that the base component is com_content then how can the Joomla 3.1 platform a.p.i tell me that it stores its data in #__content table.

Answer (score 2):

The content types table provides information on this if your component has stored rows there. Using this you can programmatically get both the db table as well as the JTable data. In 3.2. there are a couple of places where this is used nicely such as in the ordering field and in versioning.

Comment: I'm actually interested in how this could be done. Could you provide a small example please Elin?

Comment: One place I was thinking about is here, if you know the name of the content type https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/cms/form/field/ordering.php#L81 Also you can look at some of the tag handling and the observer classes.